# why do i get a type error with my __gt__ operation overloading

Tags: python, oop, boolean, gt, operands

I created a class 'Kaart' in python and this a playing card with a rank and a suit
My ranking is the following ranking = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'B','V','H','A']

I want to define the greater than operand as follows:

If you have 2 playing cards I have defined the greather than rule as follows:

```
class speelkaart():
   def __init__(self,colour,value):
      self.value = value
      self.colour = colour
      list = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'B', 'V', 'K', 'A']
   def __repr__(self):
      return f"""speelkaart({self.colour},{self.value})"""
   def __eq__(self, n):
      if isinstance(n,speelkaart):
         if self.value == n.value and self.colour== n.colour:
            return True
         else:
            return False
      return NotImplemented
   def __gt__(self, n):
      if isinstance(n,speelkaart):
         if list.index(self.value) > list.index(n.value):
            return True
         else:
            return False
      return NotImplemented


kaart1 = speelkaart(1,5)
kaart2 = speelkaart(1,5)
kaart3 = speelkaart(2,3)
kaart4 = speelkaart(1,'B')

print(kaart1 == kaart2)
print(kaart1 == kaart3)
print(kaart1 > kaart3)
# print(kaart4 > kaart1)

list = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'B', 'V', 'K', 'A']

print(f"""{kaart1} has a value of {kaart1.value} and has a ranking of {list.index(kaart1.value)}\n{kaart4} has a value of {kaart4.value} and has a ranking of {list.index(kaart4.value)}""")
print(f"""so why do I get an TypeError in the __gt__(self,other) if i compare it with the list.index(self.waarde) and list.index(other.waarde)""")
print(list.index(kaart1.value) > list.index(kaart4.value))
```

I am trying to get an answer I expect a clear answer why my **gt** doesn't work

Comment: `list` is a local variable in the `__init__` method, you can't access it from the `__gt__` method. It should be `self.list`.

Comment: If it's the same for all instances, use a class attribute instead of an instance attribute. Assign it outside the `__init__` method. But you still have to use `self.list` to access it from `__gt__`. It's also not a good idea to use `list` as the name, since it's the same as the built-in type.

Comment: If you are getting an error, **post the full error message including the stack trace**. Why would you omit that information?

Comment: What do you expect `list.index(self.value)` to do and why?